# Django: how to add a step after the default authentication/login code

Tags: django

I'm building out my first Django Project, and I'm always grateful that authentication steps are provided in modern frameworks, but I'm having trouble seeing how/where to customize the login process to do an additional step behind the scenes.

I followed a tutorial to use the Django authentication, and everything is working great. I made a registration/login.html page that includes 'next' for where to take the users. I include the Django urls for authentication in mysite/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('familytree/', include('familytree.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

- In settings.py, I specify that I want users to go to the dashboard page after logging in:

  LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'

  LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'landing'

**The question:** I'd like to add one other step: after a user successfully authenticates, make a record in a new logins table (and *then* let them continue on to the dashboard). I've seen into about writing my own authentication backend, but I think I just want to expand on the existing default authentication. Where's the right place to add this step? At first I was thinking I could change the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL to some other step (and then have *that* proceed to dashboard), but what I want isn't really a url.... not sure if middleware would be more appropriate? OR is there some way to sort of extend the login code to add this other action?

Comment: You can make your own login view that inherits from the django standard login view but adds any desired extra functionality

Comment: Thanks! That sounds right, but when I search for something like this, I keep finding info on how to customize the view templates, to customize what the user sees, but I'm looking for something behind the scenes: a function (someplace like views.py) that can define saving a new record after a the standard authentication succeeds, before the user reaches LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL. Any suggestions for where I can find an example like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, see if this is needed. On every new login, Django updates `last_login` on the user model. If this is really different from what you want, read on.

You can override the [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views) and reimplement `LoginView`'s form_valid.

First, we create a new app to handle the authentication. We will only override one bit, and delegate the rest to django.contrib.auth, but we may want to override more in the future, so let's keep it neatly organized.

So, create the new app, myauth:
`python ./manage.py startapp myauth`

And add it to INSTALLED_APPS in settings:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS=[
    ...
    "myauth",
]
```

Now edit the standard views.py
`# myauth/views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView as BaseLoginView
from django.utils import timezone
from myauth.models import LoginAudit


class LoginView(BaseLoginView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # A redirect is just a HttpResponse, so you can grab and hold it
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        LoginAudit.objects.create(user=self.request.user, logged_in_at=timezone.now())
        # And then release
        return response
```

And urls
`#myauth/urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views as my_auth_views  # for clarity

urlpatterns = (
    path('login/', my_auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    # ... see list at:
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views
)
```

And finally your root urlconf:

`#mysite/urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = (
    ...
    path('accounts/', include('myauth.urls'))
    ...
)
```

For completeness, the LoginAudit model:

`#myauth/models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class LoginAudit(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='login_events')
    logged_in_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    # of course you can also override LogoutView() and set this field :)
    # logged_out_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: This looks like just what I need! Thanks so much for taking the time to put this together- I'll try it out!

Comment: hey Melvyn- I'm having a little trouble and want to make sure I'm in the right spot: should the new 'myauth' directory be a sibling to my project directory, under templates?

Comment: myauth is a new app, sorry forgot about that.